# How to check for old passwords using Spring "matches" method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

```
@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Autowired
private OldPasswordsService oldPasswordsService;

Optional<OldPasswords> list = oldPasswordsService.findEncryptedPassword(passwordEncoder.encode("new password entered form web reset form"));
            OldPasswords value = list.get();
            boolean matches = passwordEncoder.matches("new password entered form web reset form", value.getEncryptedPassword());

            if (matches)
            {
                return new ResponseEntity<>("PASSWORD_ALREADY_USED", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
            else
            {
                OldPasswords oldPasswords = new OldPasswords();
                oldPasswords.setEncryptedPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(resetDTO.getPassword()));
                oldPasswordsService.save(oldPasswords);
            }
```

Table for old passwords:

```
@Table(name = "old_passwords")
public class OldPasswords implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "encrypted_password", length = 255)
    private String encryptedPassword;

    @Column(name = "password_owner_id", length = 4)
    private Integer passwordOwnerId;

    @Column(name = "created_at")
    @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
```

But I get `java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present`.
Do you know how I can implement a logic which compares old and new passwords?

EDIT:
I tried this design:

SQL query:

```
public List<OldPasswords> findByOwnerId(Integer ownerId) {
        String hql = "select e from " + OldPasswords.class.getName() + " e where e.passwordOwnerId = :passwordOwnerId ORDER BY e.createdAt DESC";
        TypedQuery<OldPasswords> query = entityManager.createQuery(hql, OldPasswords.class).setMaxResults(3).setParameter("passwordOwnerId", ownerId);
        List<OldPasswords> list = query.getResultList();
        return list;
    }
```

Endpoint:

```
@PostMapping("reset_password")
  public ResponseEntity<?> reset(@RequestBody PasswordResetDTO resetDTO) {
    return this.userService.findByLogin(resetDTO.getName()).map(user -> {

        Integer userId = user.getId();

        List<OldPasswords> list = oldPasswordsService.findByOwnerId(userId);

        if(!list.isEmpty() && !list.isEmpty()) {

            for (int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++){
                OldPasswords value = list.get(i);

                boolean matches = passwordEncoder.matches(resetDTO.getPassword(), value.getEncryptedPassword());
                if (matches) {
                    return new ResponseEntity<>("PASSWORD_ALREADY_USED", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
                }
            }
        }

        OldPasswords oldPasswords = new OldPasswords();
        oldPasswords.setEncryptedPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(resetDTO.getPassword()));
        oldPasswords.setPasswordOwnerId(userId);
        oldPasswordsService.save(oldPasswords);

        user.setEncryptedPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(resetDTO.getPassword()));

        user.setResetPasswordToken(null);
        userService.save(user);
        return ok().build();
    }).orElseGet(() -> notFound().build());
}
```

But when I change the code several times with the same password the error `PASSWORD_ALREADY_USED` is not shown.

Comment: What exactly does `OldPasswords value = list.get();` do?

Comment: it get's a line from the DB which matches the current password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you code has several problems.

### 1. The type of 'passwordEncoder'

There are different types of password encoder, depending on the actual used encoding algorithm.
If the type of 'passwordEncoder' is e.g., MD5, SHA1 you will most likely have a password collision, as you expect the passwords to be unique.

Means if a user has a weak password e.g., "topSecret123", and another user has the same password "topSecret123", you method

```
oldPasswordsService.findEncryptedPassword(...)
```

will return multiple entries, instead of one.

That will result in e.g., a `NonUniqueResultException` or something.

#### 1.1 A possible solution:

Associated the password with the username. Fetch the user given by the userId (or something similar) and make the password checks with that user's password.

#### 1.2 Another possible solution

Use a e.g., `BCryptPasswordEncoder`. This type `PasswordEncoder` takes care of adding a salt to your has. This avoids having possible duplicate entries in your database.
These types of password encoders are unable to calculate the password or check if a password matches if only the "password" is provided. As they are using a "salt" with your encoded password, these types of password encoders need the (salt+hashed) password as input, in order to check if a provided password matches.

### 2. The actual problem

The code

```
OldPasswords value = list.get();
```

is the problem. The `Optional<OldPasswords>` may contain a `null` value.
A call `.get()` on an `Optional` will `null` value will result in `java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present`.

```
Optional<OldPasswords> list = oldPasswordsService.findEncryptedPassword(passwordEncoder.encode("new password entered form web reset form"));

if (!list.isPresent()) {
 return new ResponseEntity<>("The old password value you've entered is incorrect", HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
}

OldPasswords value = list.get();
boolean matches = passwordEncoder.matches("new password entered form web reset form", value.getEncryptedPassword());

if (matches)
{
    return new ResponseEntity<>("PASSWORD_ALREADY_USED", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
else
{
    OldPasswords oldPasswords = new OldPasswords();
    oldPasswords.setEncryptedPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(resetDTO.getPassword()));
    oldPasswordsService.save(oldPasswords);
}
```

### 3. OldPasswords entities

You neither have to make the `@Id` column `unique=true`, nor `nullable=false` no `updateable=false`.

### 4. Mixing layers

The code you've posted uses services and updates domain objects.
**And** it does return a `ResponseEntity`. You clearly mix different layers of the application into one.

### 5. Exposing information

You expose the information, that the (new) password chosen is already used by another user! Don't do that! That adds up because of point 1. I've listed.

## Edit:

After the question was updated, I want to update my answer as well.
As the code snipped in the updated question does not compile, I wanted to make a very simple, basic example based on what I know from the code snippets.

I do not comment on the concept of the "reset password" design as showed in the question, as lots of code is missing in between.

The whole code including tests can be found here: https://github.com/mschallar/so_oldpasswords_example

The code for the funtion requested in the question is:

```
@PostMapping("reset_password")
public ResponseEntity<?> reset(@RequestBody PasswordResetDTO resetDTO) {

    Optional<User> findByLogin = this.userService.findByLogin(resetDTO.getName());

    if (!findByLogin.isPresent()) {
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }

    User user = findByLogin.get();
    Integer userId = user.getUserId();

    String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(resetDTO.getPassword());

    for (OldPasswords oldPasswords : oldPasswordsService.findByOwnerId(userId)) {

        if (passwordEncoder.matches(resetDTO.getPassword(), oldPasswords.getEncryptedPassword())) {
            // Information: Don't do that! Don't reveal that another user already has such a password!
            log.info("Password already used.");
            return new ResponseEntity<>("PASSWORD_ALREADY_USED", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

    }

    OldPasswords oldPasswords = new OldPasswords();
    oldPasswords.setEncryptedPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(encodedPassword));
    oldPasswords.setPasswordOwnerId(userId);
    oldPasswordsService.save(oldPasswords);

    user.setEncryptedPassword(encodedPassword);

    user.setResetPasswordToken(null);
    userService.save(user);

    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();

}
```

Comment: I added one additional test. Can you advice why it's not working please?

Comment: What's the error now after the update? The same as before? If the query throws an error, than you probably have the wrong table name. The table name is, according to your domain object "old_passwords", but you use "OldPasswords" in your query.

Comment: the table name is not a issue. I don't get any exception so looks like it's a logic problem. Can you check the code after EDIT section, please?

Comment: @PeterPenzov I've updated my answer. Added code and a link to a working example. But from what I see, I think you reset password concept is flawed. But that's not the scope of your question.

Comment: Is there any other design that is better than that?

Comment: as you can see I have limited the available passwords to one user. I don't have other idea what design should be more appropriate.

Comment: Thats up for another question, or better do some researching in that area. Is there anything else I can do? If not mark the most appropriate and helpful answer as "accepted"

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

check that the if the list of optional type contains valid required value

```
Optional<OldPasswords> list = oldPasswordsService.findEncryptedPassword(passwordEncoder.encode("new password entered form web reset form"));
OldPasswords value = list.orElse(null);

if(value != null) {
    boolean matches = passwordEncoder.matches("new password entered form web reset form", value.getEncryptedPassword());
    if (matches) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("PASSWORD_ALREADY_USED", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    OldPasswords oldPasswords = new OldPasswords();
    oldPasswords.setEncryptedPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(resetDTO.getPassword()));
    oldPasswordsService.save(oldPasswords);
    return new ResponseEntity<>("New Password Saved" , HttpStatus.OK);
}
return new ResponseEntity<>("Incorrect Password Provided" , HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
```

or like @Manuel suggested

```
Optional<OldPasswords> list = oldPasswordsService.findEncryptedPassword(passwordEncoder.encode("new password entered form web reset form"));

if(list.isPresent()) {
    OldPasswords value = list.get();
    boolean matches = passwordEncoder.matches("new password entered form web reset form", value.getEncryptedPassword());
    if (matches) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("PASSWORD_ALREADY_USED", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    OldPasswords oldPasswords = new OldPasswords();
    oldPasswords.setEncryptedPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(resetDTO.getPassword()));
    oldPasswordsService.save(oldPasswords);
    return new ResponseEntity<>("New Password Saved" , HttpStatus.OK);
}
return new ResponseEntity<>("Incorrect Password Provided" , HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
```

Comment: Use the `isPresent()` on the `Optional`, instead of using `orElse(null)` and checking for `null` afterwards. See my answer as an example. Java took care of those `null` cases with the `isPresent()` already.

Comment: @mss I get `Cannot resolve method 'orElse' in 'OldPasswords'`

Comment: The code does **not** compile. 1st because of the issue mentioned in my comment above, and 2nd because `get()` is a method on `Optional` but not `OldPasswords`. @mss is calling `orElse()` after `get()`.

Comment: @Manuel  Thanks, I reviewed and added like you suggested.

Comment: @PeterPenzov, updated the code, it should not give any compilation error now.

Comment: I added one more attempt. Can you advice why it's not working, please?

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this using a simple solution.

```
    BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
    if (encoder.matches(newPassword, oldPassword)) 
    {
          System.out.println("Successfully logged in!");

    }
      else 
           {
                System.out.println("Incorrect Password.");
            }
```

`newPassword` and `oldPassword` must be in **String** so that it matches both passwords.

Comment: Thanks. I tried one additional attempt - see the edited post. Can you advice where I'm wrong?

Comment: I didn't get what you actually want to do.