# Grails with Spring Security: How do I keep a password history to prevent password reuse

Tags: grails, spring-security

For compliance reasons, we need to prevent users from reusing their passwords. I found this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60626886/how-to-check-for-old-passwords-using-spring-matches-method/), which is very, very helpful, but I can't find an example implementation for a Grails application.

In our app, a user's password may be reset in two ways: an "edit user" view visible to admins and a self-service password reset flow.  Ideally, I would like to perform this check during the Spring Security password encoding step to ensure it is applied regardless of which user action changes the password.

What's the best way to do that in Grails?

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question here:

**Short answer:**

I found the `personPasswordEncoderListener` defined in `resources.groovy` referenced a `PersonPasswordEncoderListener` class in `src/main/groovy`. That's where I needed to insert my logic.

**Full answer:**

First, I added a `Password` class to record the password history for each user

```
package com.company

import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode

@EqualsAndHashCode(includes = ["person", "hash"])
class Password {
    Person person
    String hash
    Date dateCreated

    static belongsTo = Person

    static constraints = {
        hash unique: "person"
    }

    static mapping = {
        version(false)
    }
}
```

Then, a `PasswordDataService` to encapsulate persistence logic.

```
package com.company

import grails.gorm.services.Service

@Service(Password)
interface PasswordDataService {
    Password get(Serializable id)

    List<Password> findAllByPerson(Person person)

    Password save(Password password)
}
```

Then, I added the `PasswordService` to handle the business logic.

```
package com.company

import grails.gorm.transactions.Transactional
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource
import org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder
import com.company.exception.InvalidResourceException

@Transactional
class PasswordService {

    MessageSource messageSource
    PasswordDataService passwordDataService
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder

    void preventPasswordReuse(Person person) {
        findAllByPerson(person).each { password ->
            if (passwordEncoder.matches(person.password, password.hash)) {
                String msg = messageSource.getMessage("passwordService.exception.passwordReused", [] as Object[], "You cannot use a password you have used before", LocaleContextHolder.locale)
                throw new InvalidResourceException(msg)
            }
        }
    }

    void recordPassword(Person person) {
        save(new Password(person: person, hash: person.password))
    }

    /* *** Data Service Pass-through Methods *** */

    Password get(Long id) {
        passwordDataService.get(id)
    }

    List<Password> findAllByPerson(Person person) {
        passwordDataService.findAllByPerson(person)
    }

    Password save(Password password) {
        passwordDataService.save(password)
    }
}
```

Then, I added calls to the `PasswordService` in `PersonPasswordEncoderListener.encodePasswordForEvent(..)`.  The vast majority of `PersonPasswordEncoderListener` was already written (I only added 4 lines), but I'll include it in its entirety here for context and annotate the new lines with `//added`

```
package com.company

import grails.events.annotation.gorm.Listener
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.AbstractPersistenceEvent
import org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.PreInsertEvent
import org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.PreUpdateEvent
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired

@CompileStatic
class PersonPasswordEncoderListener {

    @Autowired
    SpringSecurityService springSecurityService

    @Autowired //added
    PasswordService passwordService //added

    @Listener(Person)
    void onPreInsertEvent(PreInsertEvent event) {
        encodePasswordForEvent(event)
    }

    @Listener(Person)
    void onPreUpdateEvent(PreUpdateEvent event) {
        encodePasswordForEvent(event)
    }

    private void encodePasswordForEvent(AbstractPersistenceEvent event) {
        if (event.entityObject instanceof Person) {
            Person person = event.entityObject as Person
            if (person.password && ((event instanceof PreInsertEvent) || (event instanceof PreUpdateEvent && person.isDirty('password')))) {
                passwordService.preventPasswordReuse(person) //added
                event.getEntityAccess().setProperty('password', encodePassword(person.password))
                passwordService.recordPassword(person) //added
            }
        }
    }

    private String encodePassword(String password) {
        springSecurityService?.passwordEncoder ? springSecurityService.encodePassword(password) : password
    }
}
```

This created a problem because Spring Security wrapped the `InvalidResourceException` that I was throwing in `PasswordService.preventPasswordReuse` in an `UndeclaredThrowableException`, which hid the exception message I needed to pass along to my view.  I resolved this by adding an exception handler to the exception handling trait that all our controllers implement to uncover the cause of the `UndeclaredThrowableException`.

```
    def defaultExceptionHandler(Exception e) {
        ... pre-existing exception handler code removed ...
    }

    def undeclaredThrowableException(final UndeclaredThrowableException e) {
        defaultExceptionHandler(e?.cause as Exception ?: e)
    }
```